# Bootstrap 4 : Panel not disappearing

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap 4, and I'm having a tough time with this. On this page [wyckofftwosmartcookies.com](http://www.wyckofftwosmartcookies.com) the recipe section has three tabs, then a vertical navigation that selects between cookie types.

The first one displays correct then when you switch cookies instead of fading the first remains and the next selection appears underneath. I spent the last three hours looking at this and am missing something obvious. Any help or suggestions where to look would be greatly appreciated. Need to get this done for my daughters project =)

```css
body{max-width:1440px;margin:auto;background-color:#f6f6f6}
 #mobile-recipies{display:none}
 #recipie-selector-desktop{display:none}
 #mobile-selector{display: block}
 .mor img {width:40%}
 .hero-background{background-image:url("2 smart cookies hero desktop.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;height:500px}
 .hero-headline{font-family:'Permanent Marker';color:#000111;font-size:36px}
 .cookiefont-white{font-family:'Cookie',cursive ;font-size:1.5em;padding:24 0 0px;color:#666;font-weight:400}
 .bg-drkgreen {background-color:#166937}
 .bg-black{background-color:#232020}
 .bg-orange{background-color:#F7941D}
 .bg-blue{background-color:#3A71B8}
 .font-white{color:#fff}
 .section-lead-copy{font-family:'pacifico';font-size:24px;color:#888888;text-align: center}
 .menu-item-font-white{font-family:'Cookie';font-size:20px;color:#666666;text-align: center}
 .description-header{font-family:'Cookie';font-size:22px ;font-weight:600;color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center}
 .spacer{padding-top:65px; padding-bottom:45px}
 .spacer-b{padding-top:35px; padding-bottom:5px}
 .spacer-c{padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:5px}
 .spacer-d{padding-top:10px}
 img.center {display: block;margin: 0 auto}
 
/* recipie box */
 #mobile-recipies .btn-link {color:#000000}
 #recipie-desktop a{color:#000000}
 #recipie-desktop .nav-link.active {background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'pacifico'}
 #recipie-desktop ul{padding-left: 3px}
 .mb-0{font-family:'pacifico';color:#000}
 .card-header{background-color:#ffffff}
 .border-box{width:100%; border:dotted medium #000;border-radius: 5px;max-height: 700px}
 .recipie-headline{font-family: 'pacifico';font-weight:400;font-size:30px;color:#000}
 .recipie-subheadline{font-family:'roboto';font-size:14px;color:#999}
 
 /* Ecommerce Styling */
  .rep-product-Headline{font-family:'roboto';font-height:18px;color:#000000}
  .rep-product-description{font-family:'roboto';font-size:16px;color:#888}
  .rep-product-price{font-family:'Permanent Marker';font-size:45px}
  .rep-image-box{width:50px;height:75px}
 .ecomm-format button{background-color:#f6f6f6;font-family:'roboto';color:#000;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold}
 .ecomm-format img {width:250px;height:275px}
 @media (max-width: 995px){
 #recipie-selector-desktop{display:none}
 #mobile-selector{display: block}
 .mor img {width:40%}
#ecomm-format img{width:200px; height:225px}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.3/default/snipcart.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recipie-desktop">
<div class ="container-fluid">
<div class = "border-box">
<div class ="recipie-headline"> Four Awesome Cookie Mixes </div>
<hr>
<div class ="spacer-c"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-sfcatc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-sfcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-sfcatc-tab" aria-selected="true">Santa's Favorite Cookies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-wsc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-wsc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-wsc-tab" aria-selected="false">Wintry Sugar Cookies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-rc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-rc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-rc-tab" aria-selected="false">Reindeer Cookies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-ccoc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-ccoc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-ccoc-tab" aria-selected="false">Chocolate Chip & Oatmeal Cookies</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-sfcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-sfcatc-tab">
   <div hidden id="snipcart" data-api-key="NmM2YTU4NzUtZGUwZS00OTAwLWFiZTEtNDQ2ZmE5ZTQwMDEzNjM2ODY4NTk3OTAxMjYwMDA5"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.3/default/snipcart.js"></script> 
   <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-sfcatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcatc-tab" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-sfcd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcd-tab" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-sfcv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcv-tab" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-sfcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcatc-tab">
 <div class = "row">
 <div class ="col-5" >
  <div class ="spacer-c"></div>
    <div class="ecomm-format"><img src="sfcjar.png"></div>
 
  
 </div> 
 
 <div class ="col-4">
 <div class ="spacer-c"></div> 
 <div class ="rep-product-Headline">Holiday M&M Cookie Mix in a decorative 16oz Jar</div>
 <div class ="rep-product-price">$11.99</div> 
  <div class ="spacer-d"></div>
 <div class ="ecomm-format">
 <button class="snipcart-add-item" data-item-id="Santa's Favorite Cookies" data-item-price="11.99" data-item-url="/product/Santas-favorite-cookie-jar" data-item-description="M&M Cookie Mix"data-item-image="sfcjar.png" data-item-name="Santa's Favorite M&M Cookie">Order Now</button></div>
  
  
 </div>  
  </div>  
  </div>
 
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-sfcd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcd-tab">
   <div class ="row">
 <div class ="col-4">
  <br>
  <div class ="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div> 
 <ul>
  <li>¾ cup( 1 and ½ sticks) unsalted butter,softened</li>
  <li>1 large egg</li>
  <li>½ tablespoon vanilla extract</li>
 </ul>
  </div> 
   <div class ="col-6">
   <br>
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
 <ul>
  <li>Preheat oven to 350 degrees F. </li>
  <li>Beat butter, egg, and vanilla extract in large mixing bowl until blended. </li>
  <li>Add mason jar mix and mix well. </li>
  <li>Drop by rounded tablespoon onto parchment paper lined baking sheet. </li>
   <li>Bake for 9 to 11 minutes or until lightly golden brown. </li>
  <li>Cool on baking sheets for 2 minutes before moving to cooling rack. </li>  
    </ul>   
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-sfcv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcv-tab">video</div>
</div> 
    
 </div></div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-wsc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-wsc-tab">
    <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-wscatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-wscd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscd" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-wscv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscv" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="nav-wscatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscatc-tab">wsc atc</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-wscd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscd-tab">
  <div class ="row">
 <div class ="col-4">
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div> 
 <ul>
  <li>½ cup unsalted butter(softened)</li>
  <li>1 egg, room temperature</li>
  <li>½ teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
  <li>½ cup sour cream</li>

  
 </ul>
   </div>  
   <div class ="col-6">
  
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
 <ul>
  </li>
    <li>Mix all ingredients together and roll out to ¼ inch thickness on lightly floured surface.</li>

<li>Chill dough for about an hour before using cookie cutters to shape. Add sprinkles if desired.</li>

<li>Bake at 350 degrees for 10 to 12 minutes(do not overbake)</li>

  
    </ul>   
   </div>
   
   </div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-wscv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscv-tab">Video</div>
</div> 
  </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-rc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-rc-tab">
 <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-rcatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-rcdir-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcdir" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcdir" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-rcvid-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcvid" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcvid" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-rc" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-rcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcatc-tab">ATC</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcdir-tab">
   <div class ="row">
 <div class ="col-4">
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div> 
 <ul>
  <li>½ cup softened butter</li>
  <li>1 egg </li>
  <li>1 teaspoon vanilla</li>
 </ul>
   </div>  
   <div class ="col-6">
  
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
 <ul>
  <li>Dump jar in a large mixing bowl</li>
  <li>add ½ cup softened butter</li>
  <li>add 1 egg</li><li>add 1 teaspoon vanilla.</li>
  <li>Mix well and drop onto a cookie sheet lined with parchment paper. </li>
        <li>Bake at 375 degrees for 8 to 10 minutes</li>

  
    </ul>   
   </div>
   
   </div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcvid-tab">RC Video</div>
</div> </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-ccoc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-ccoc-tab">
    <nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-ccocatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-ccocd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocd" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-ccocv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocv" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-ccocatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocatc-tab">atc ccoc</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-ccocd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocd-tab">
   
   <div class ="row">
 <div class ="col-4">
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div> 
 <ul>
  <li>1 egg, slightly beaten</li>
  <li>1 teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
  <li>1 stick butter, softened</li>

 </ul>
   </div>  
   <div class ="col-6">
  
   <div class ="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
 <ul>
  <li>Preheat oven to 375 degrees.</li> 
  <li>Empty jar contents into a large mixing bowl</li> 
  <li>Add the egg</li>, <li>Add the vanilla</li>
  <li> Add the butter and mix well</li>
  <li>Drop by spoonfuls onto an ungreased cookie sheet about 2 inches apart</li>
  <li>Bake for 8 to 10 minutes or until the edges are golden brown</li>
  <li>Remove to a wire rack and let cool</li>

  
    </ul>   
   </div>
   
   </div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-ccocv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocv-tab">ccoc v</div>
</div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
 
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your HTML code.

In this div `tab-content` you haven't added all your `tab-pane` divs.

Hope this will help you.

```css
  body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f6f6f6
}

#mobile-recipies {
  display: none
}

#recipie-selector-desktop {
  display: none
}

#mobile-selector {
  display: block
}

.mor img {
  width: 40%
}

.hero-background {
  background-image: url("2 smart cookies hero desktop.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500px
}

.hero-headline {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker';
  color: #000111;
  font-size: 36px
}

.cookiefont-white {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 24 0 0px;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 400
}

.bg-drkgreen {
  background-color: #166937
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #232020
}

.bg-orange {
  background-color: #F7941D
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #3A71B8
}

.font-white {
  color: #fff
}

.section-lead-copy {
  font-family: 'pacifico';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: center
}

.menu-item-font-white {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center
}

.description-header {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center
}

.spacer {
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 45px
}

.spacer-b {
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

.spacer-c {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

.spacer-d {
  padding-top: 10px
}

img.center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto
}


/* recipie box */

#mobile-recipies .btn-link {
  color: #000000
}

#recipie-desktop a {
  color: #000000
}

#recipie-desktop .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'pacifico'
}

#recipie-desktop ul {
  padding-left: 3px
}

.mb-0 {
  font-family: 'pacifico';
  color: #000
}

.card-header {
  background-color: #ffffff
}

.border-box {
  width: 100%;
  border: dotted medium #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-height: 700px
}

.recipie-headline {
  font-family: 'pacifico';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000
}

.recipie-subheadline {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999
}


/* Ecommerce Styling */

.rep-product-Headline {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-height: 18px;
  color: #000000
}

.rep-product-description {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #888
}

.rep-product-price {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker';
  font-size: 45px
}

.rep-image-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px
}

.ecomm-format button {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.ecomm-format img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 275px
}

@media (max-width: 995px) {
  #recipie-selector-desktop {
    display: none
  }
  #mobile-selector {
    display: block
  }
  .mor img {
    width: 40%
  }
  #ecomm-format img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 225px
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.3/default/snipcart.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recipie-desktop">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="border-box">
      <div class="recipie-headline"> Four Awesome Cookie Mixes </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="spacer-c"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-sfcatc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-sfcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-sfcatc-tab" aria-selected="true">Santa's Favorite Cookies</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-wsc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-wsc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-wsc-tab" aria-selected="false">Wintry Sugar Cookies</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-rc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-rc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-rc-tab" aria-selected="false">Reindeer Cookies</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-ccoc-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-ccoc" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-ccoc-tab" aria-selected="false">Chocolate Chip & Oatmeal Cookies</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-sfcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-sfcatc-tab">
              <div hidden id="snipcart" data-api-key="NmM2YTU4NzUtZGUwZS00OTAwLWFiZTEtNDQ2ZmE5ZTQwMDEzNjM2ODY4NTk3OTAxMjYwMDA5"></div>
              <script src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.3/default/snipcart.js"></script>
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-sfcatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcatc-tab" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-sfcd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcd-tab" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-sfcv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sfcv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-sfcv-tab" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-sfcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcatc-tab">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                      <div class="spacer-c"></div>
                      <div class="ecomm-format"><img src="sfcjar.png"></div>


                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4">
                      <div class="spacer-c"></div>
                      <div class="rep-product-Headline">Holiday M&M Cookie Mix in a decorative 16oz Jar</div>
                      <div class="rep-product-price">$11.99</div>
                      <div class="spacer-d"></div>
                      <div class="ecomm-format">
                        <button class="snipcart-add-item" data-item-id="Santa's Favorite Cookies" data-item-price="11.99" data-item-url="/product/Santas-favorite-cookie-jar" data-item-description="M&M Cookie Mix" data-item-image="sfcjar.png" data-item-name="Santa's Favorite M&M Cookie">Order Now</button></div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-sfcd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcd-tab">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <br>
                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>¾ cup( 1 and ½ sticks) unsalted butter,softened</li>
                        <li>1 large egg</li>
                        <li>½ tablespoon vanilla extract</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <br>
                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Preheat oven to 350 degrees F. </li>
                        <li>Beat butter, egg, and vanilla extract in large mixing bowl until blended. </li>
                        <li>Add mason jar mix and mix well. </li>
                        <li>Drop by rounded tablespoon onto parchment paper lined baking sheet. </li>
                        <li>Bake for 9 to 11 minutes or until lightly golden brown. </li>
                        <li>Cool on baking sheets for 2 minutes before moving to cooling rack. </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-sfcv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sfcv-tab">video</div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-wsc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-wsc-tab">
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-wscatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-wscd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscd" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-wscv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-wscv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-wscv" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="nav-wscatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscatc-tab">wsc atc</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-wscd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscd-tab">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>½ cup unsalted butter(softened)</li>
                        <li>1 egg, room temperature</li>
                        <li>½ teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
                        <li>½ cup sour cream</li>


                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">

                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Mix all ingredients together and roll out to ¼ inch thickness on lightly floured surface.</li>

                        <li>Chill dough for about an hour before using cookie cutters to shape. Add sprinkles if desired.</li>

                        <li>Bake at 350 degrees for 10 to 12 minutes(do not overbake)</li>


                      </ul>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-wscv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-wscv-tab">Video</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-rc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-rc-tab">
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-rcatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-rcdir-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcdir" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcdir" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-rcvid-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-rcvid" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-rcvid" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-rc" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-rcatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcatc-tab">ATC</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcdir-tab">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>½ cup softened butter</li>
                        <li>1 egg </li>
                        <li>1 teaspoon vanilla</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">

                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Dump jar in a large mixing bowl</li>
                        <li>add ½ cup softened butter</li>
                        <li>add 1 egg</li>
                        <li>add 1 teaspoon vanilla.</li>
                        <li>Mix well and drop onto a cookie sheet lined with parchment paper. </li>
                        <li>Bake at 375 degrees for 8 to 10 minutes</li>


                      </ul>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rcvid-tab">RC Video</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-ccoc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-ccoc-tab">
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-ccocatc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocatc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocatc" aria-selected="true">About The Cookies</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-ccocd-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocd" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocd" aria-selected="false">Directions</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-ccocv-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-ccocv" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-ccocv" aria-selected="false">Video Directions</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-ccocatc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocatc-tab">atc ccoc</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-ccocd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocd-tab">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">What You Need To Have:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>1 egg, slightly beaten</li>
                        <li>1 teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
                        <li>1 stick butter, softened</li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">

                      <div class="recipie-subheadline">Directions:</div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Preheat oven to 375 degrees.</li>
                        <li>Empty jar contents into a large mixing bowl</li>
                        <li>Add the egg</li>,
                        <li>Add the vanilla</li>
                        <li> Add the butter and mix well</li>
                        <li>Drop by spoonfuls onto an ungreased cookie sheet about 2 inches apart</li>
                        <li>Bake for 8 to 10 minutes or until the edges are golden brown</li>
                        <li>Remove to a wire rack and let cool</li>


                      </ul>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-ccocv" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-ccocv-tab">ccoc v</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
```